# How to set BLE advertisement packet's device name field

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the API to the build an advertisement packet. I pass `true` to `setIncludeDeviceName`

```
    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
            .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(TimeProfile.TIME_SERVICE))
            .build();
```

The API encodes the device model number in the advertising packet. For my app however, the device name for the advertisement packet should be come from a string hard coded into the app

```
private static final String DEVICE_NAME = "My_Device_Name";
```

Is there any way to customize the device name in the advertising packet? I don't see any way to do that in the docs for [AdvertiseData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.html) or for [AdvertiseData.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the *"setIncludeDeviceName"* from your *data* AdvertiseData 
object and define a scan response AdvertiseData object

```
AdvertiseData scanResponse = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
        .build();
```

Then start advertising using the scanResponse as well

```
bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()
          .startAdvertising(advSettings, data, scanResponse, advCallback);
```

Full example:

```
AdvertiseSettings advSettings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
    .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
    .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
    .setConnectable(true)
    .build();

AdvertiseData advData = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
    .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)
    .addServiceUuid(mCurrentServiceFragment.getServiceUUID())
    .build();

AdvertiseData advScanResponse = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
    .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
    .build();

AdvertiseCallback advCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
        Log.e(TAG, "Not broadcasting: " + errorCode);
        int statusText;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED:
                Log.w(TAG, "ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED");
                break;
            case ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE:
                Log.w(TAG, "ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE");
                break;
            case ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED:
                Log.w(TAG, "ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED");
                break;
            case ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                Log.w(TAG, "ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR");
                break;
            case ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS:
                Log.w(TAG, "ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS");
                break;
            default:
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Unhandled error: " + errorCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        Log.v(TAG, "Advertising started");
    }
};

bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()
          .startAdvertising(advSettings, advData, advScanResponse, advCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you have to use the [BluetoothAdapter.setName(String name);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#setName(java.lang.String)) method for this.

Comment: This is the proper way to set the name of the adapter.